# apply a function to the nan values and got UnboundLocalError: local variable 'val' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file with a column named logo, some rows have a picture path and some rows are blank. I want to fill the blank rows with one picture and here's my code and got the error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'val' referenced before assignment

```
def g(row):
    if row['logo'] == np.nan:
        val = str(r"path\yellow_m.png")
    else:
        pass
    return val
```

```
operator['logo'] = operator.apply(g, axis=1)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-261a706495c6> in <module>
----> 1 operator['logo'] = operator.apply(g, axis=1)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwds)
   7546             kwds=kwds,
   7547         )
-> 7548         return op.get_result()
   7549 
   7550     def applymap(self, func) -> "DataFrame":

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in get_result(self)
    178             return self.apply_raw()
    179 
--> 180         return self.apply_standard()
    181 
    182     def apply_empty_result(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    269 
    270     def apply_standard(self):
--> 271         results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
    272 
    273         # wrap results

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    298                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
    299                     # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
--> 300                     results[i] = self.f(v)
    301                     if isinstance(results[i], ABCSeries):
    302                         # If we have a view on v, we need to make a copy because

<ipython-input-16-1de3acee1278> in g(row)
      4     else:
      5         pass
----> 6     return val

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'val' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: If your function, `val` is not defined for `else` cases.

Comment: `val` is only defined if `row['logo']` is None. If you want to use what is in `row['logo']` if it's not None, you need to do `val = row['logo']` in the `else` clause.

Answer (score 0):

if your code ran into else, val is not called.

```
def g(row):
if row['logo'] == np.nan:
    val = str(r"path\yellow_m.png")
    return val
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `return val` function will return `val` irrespective of the fact that `val` is defined or not. if `if` statement evaluates to False, then it goes to `else`. But `else` is not doing anything because of `pass`.

`val` is defined only if `row['logo']` is `None` Type. But if it is not, then it goes to `else` statement.

Now, `return` val is executed. But `val` is not defined. So an Error.

```
def g(row):
    if row['logo'] == np.nan:
        val = str(r"path\yellow_m.png")
        return val
    else:
        pass
```